# How to export a Datastax graph based on a specific traversal using DseGraphFrame

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, spark-submit, dse-graph-frames

I would like to export a DSE graph via a spark job , as per 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/dseGraphFrameExport.html

All this works fine within the spark-shell , 
I want to be doing this in Java using DseGraphFrame .
Unfortunately there is not much in the documentation

I am able to pack a jar with the following code and do a 
`spark-submit`

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Datastax Java example")
        .getOrCreate();
    DseGraphFrame dseGraphFrame = DseGraphFrameBuilder.dseGraph(args[0], spark);
    DataFrameWriter dataFrameWriter = dseGraphFrame.V().df().write();
    dataFrameWriter.csv("vertices");
```

The above works fine ,
what I want to be doing is use a specific traversal to filter what I export.
That is use something like that

```
dseGraphFrame.V().hasLabel("label").df().write();
```

The above does not work as `dseGraphFrame.V().hasLabel("label")` does not have `.df()`

Is this the correct way of doing things

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A late answer to this question, perhaps still of use:

In Java, you need to cast this to a DseGraphTraversal first. This can then be converted to a DataFrame with the `.df()` method:

```
((DseGraphTraversal)dseGraphFrame.V().hasLabel("label")).df().write();
```